# How to select the Dropdown option based on class selection using webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When the user expands the menu and chooses and option, how can I get the selected option with Selenium?

```
<select class="brand-select select-glossy user-success" name="">

<option value="All Makes">All Makes</option>

<option value="Ford">Ford</option>

<option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>

<option value="Mercury">Mercury</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `select` element and make a `Select` object our of it (need to `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`)

Use the API therein to get the first selected option:

```
WebElement selectedOption = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("brand-select"))).getFirstSelectedOption();
```